# sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; a password is required Error: Process completed with exit code 1

Tags: linux, github, apk-tools

I was running a built successfully from my editor to github and suddenly I started getting this error at the end of the build on github

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

project! building an apk file from a python kivy source code via github workflow.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? and how did you resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

The build is trying to run some commands using `sudo`. If the build used to work before, this is suspicious: if someone has hacked the github account, they may have introduced malicious commands in the build process, hoping to gain access to developers' systems with a Trojan Horse tactic.

Search for `sudo` command in the Makefiles or similar build control files; if you find it used in there, make sure you understand what those commands are trying to do and that they make sense as part of the build process.

If you don't find any instances of `sudo` by searching, it's time to review the build control files as a whole, looking for anything suspicious, like obfuscated scripts to hide the actual commands being executed. If you find anything you don't understand, find someone who does, or can conclusively say "that definitely should not be there".

If the error happens when the build process is packaging the software for distribution, you might simply need a `fakeroot` tool installed: it is a tool that allows other standard tools to more easily produce packages with embedded file/directory ownership information as `root` or some other system account (as required by the packaging specifications), while the build process does not really have privileged access to such an account locally.